# Show $R'/\mathfrak P^k \cong \oplus_{j = 0}^{k-1} \mathfrak P^j / \mathfrak P^{j+1}$ as Abelian groups, where $\mathfrak P$ is a prime ideal of $R'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

There's actually a bit more of a setup than this, and it turns out that the setup is needed for the statement to always be true.

Let $R \subset R'$ be Dedekind rings with $\mathfrak{p}$ a nonzero prime ideal of $R$ with $\mathfrak{p}R' = \mathfrak P^k$ for some nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak P$ of $R'$.

The statement $R'/\mathfrak P^k \cong \oplus_{j = 0}^{k-1} \mathfrak P^j / \mathfrak P^{j+1}$ is *not* true when $R' = \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathfrak P = 2\mathbb{Z}$, and $k = 2$--there is an element on the left with order 4 and no element on the right. So the proof will have to use the above setup, or at least parts of it. One aspect, as pointed out by Adam Hughes below, is that in this example, $k$ was chosen, whereas in the statement of the theorem, $k$ was forced upon us. However, I am still not quite sure what the isomorphism maps might be.

(My evidence for believing this is true is that it was stated as true, without proof, in Gerald Janusz's *Algebraic Number Fields*.)

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, can you reference the specific page or theorem/lemma/et cetera number in Janusz's book?

Comment: Sure. It's Theorem (and the very beginning of the proof of) 6.6. I've uploaded a picture with everything my question regards. (There's a bit of reduction that needs to be done to get to my question.)

Comment: Ahhh, I see the issue. $\mathfrak{P}$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ are not generally the same. In your example this would be $R=R'=\Bbb Z$ so that $\beta = 2$ and $k=1$, which of course trivially holds.

Comment: Right. I agree that my example doesn't show that Janusz's claim is false. However, it makes it more difficult to see why the claimed isomorphism is actually true. I tried to modify this example with $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1 + i)^2$ since $2\mathbb{Z}[i] = ((1+i)\mathbb{Z}[i])^2$, but then the two are isomorphic.

Comment: Yes I agree, but the important thing to note is you are assuming you have control over $k$--that is where you have erred: $k$ is automatically given based on $R'$, you are not allowed to choose it--if you do the result is not necessarily true. In your example you say $\beta=2$ when $R'=\Bbb Z$, but then $k=1$ is forced by the assumptions of the problem, so your case never can happen.

Comment: Thank both of you! The mistake I was making was not realizing that all of the spaces in question were vector spaces (in particular, $R/\mathfrak{p}$ vector spaces), and, because of this, all short exact sequences split.